# undesrtanding get_post_meta function

Tags: post-meta

Is there any way to avoid that when you don’t specify a $key ('') and set $single to true in get_post_meta, it returns all keys still with an array of values, instead of returning a single value only .

```
$meta = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), '', true);
print_r($meta);
//This is giving me:
//Array ( [key_1] => Array ( [0] => value_1 ), [key_2] => Array ( [0] => value_2 ) )
//And I will expect:
//Array ( [key_1] => value_1, [key_2] => value_2 )
```

I know that I can access the data writing array[key_1][0], but I don't understand why, considering that I'm declaring $single as TRUE.

I might be missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_post_meta()` calls [get_metadata()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/), the parameter description of which says:

> $single
>      (bool) (Optional) If true, return only the first value of the specified meta_key. This parameter has no effect if meta_key is not specified.
>
> Default value: false

So, since you are passing `''` as the meta_key, the `$single` parameter is ignored.

Does that explain it?

**Edit:**

If you only want the 1st value for each meta key, then just do the following:

```
array_map ('array_shift', get_post_meta (get_the_ID (), '')) ;
```

Comment: So, what should I do? Is there a way to get an array as desired: Array ( [key_1] => value_1, [key_2] => value_2 )

Comment: OK, so there's no magic word for the second parameter of the function get_post_meta to achieve it...

Comment: that's correct.